# Defining proper IAM role for Cognito SMS using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws

I created a role with policy for Cognito to publish SNS. The problem with this when scanning via terraform security, is it complains of having an overly permissive ([AVD-AWS-0057](https://aquasecurity.github.io/tfsec/v1.4.1/checks/aws/iam/no-policy-wildcards/)) since I'm using a wildcard in `Resource: ["*"]`.

So, I made a change to this to only add the Cognito user pool ARN and SNS topic ARN, but still complain of the role not having an SNS publish permission. Where in fact, the action below indicates permission.

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    principals {
      type = "Service"
      identifiers = ["cognito-idp.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    condition {
      test = "StringEquals"
      variable = "sts:ExternalId"

      values = [aws_cognito_user_pool.uam_user_pool.arn]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "iam_role" {
  name               = var.role_name
  path               = var.role_path
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_role_policy.json

  tags = var.default_tags
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "role_policy" {
  statement {
    sid = "AllowSNSPublish"
    effect  = "Allow"
    actions = ["sns:publish"]
    resources = [
      aws_sns_topic.topic.arn,
      aws_cognito_user_pool.uam_user_pool.arn
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "managed_policy" {
  name = var.role_policy_name
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.role_policy.json

  tags = var.default_tags
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "managed_policy_attach" {
  role = aws_iam_role.role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.managed_policy.arn
}
```

How do you properly set this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `"assume_role_policy"` you are referencing the ARN of the user_pool and checking this against the `sts:ExternalId` - you need to add the external-id here rather than the ARN.

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_role_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    principals {
      type = "Service"
      identifiers = ["cognito-idp.amazonaws.com"]
    }

    condition {
      test = "StringEquals"
      variable = "sts:ExternalId"

      values = ["<your-external-id>"]
    }
  }
}
```

You also don't need the ARN of the userpool in the `"role_policy"`. This document is stating "whoever has this assigned to them can `sns:publish` to `aws_sns_topic.topic.arn`" - there is no need to specifc the userpool here. This is done at the point of attaching the policy to role/user/group (e.g. `aws_iam_role.role.name`).

Comment: How does one get the external ID?

Comment: @MarkoE it's not generated by AWS but controlled by whoever manages the trust policy and supplied when calling [`AssumeRole`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html#API_AssumeRole_RequestParameters). See [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user_externalid.html) on ExternalId for more info

Comment: Thank you. I did read that yesterday, but still feel dumbfounded. What happens if the Cognito User Pool and SNS are in the same account?

Comment: Disregard my last comment. I thought there might be some kind of a dependency between the `external_id` in the `sms_configuration` block and the role itself. Thank you once again.